# tkinter - linking buttons in a for loop to a dictionary of functions {name : function}

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, lambda, python-3.5

I am trying to create a rather large list of buttons in a for loop that is also linked to their corresponding function to be called in a dictionary. There are a few similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688385/tkinter-menu-and-buttons) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951770/looping-buttons-in-tkinter-and-function-assignment) that discuss using lambda assigning the name=name, but I cant seem to figure out how to incorporate that into this specific instance where each one calls a different function in the dictionary, rather than altering a single parameter of single function.  Here is an example.

```
import tkinter as tkinter    
root = tkinter.Tk()

def funct1():
    print("Printed Func1")
def funct2():
    print("Printed Func2")

buttons_dict = {"button1": "Func1", "button2": "Func2"}

row = 0
for name in buttons_dict:
    buttons = tkinter.Button(root, text=name) # command=lambda name=name: root(name))
    buttons.grid(row=row)
    buttons.config()
    row += 1

root.mainloop()
```

What would be the correct method for assigning the name to the function when gathering the information from a dictionary like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference the function in the dictionary like this:

```
import tkinter as tkinter    
root = tkinter.Tk()

def funct1():
    print("Printed Func1")
def funct2():
    print("Printed Func2")

buttons_dict = {"button1": funct1, "button2": funct2}

row = 0
for name in buttons_dict:
    buttons = tkinter.Button(root, text=name, command=buttons_dict[name])
    buttons.grid(row=row)
    buttons.config()
    row += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, I was so focused on the command button in the loop I never even noticed that. Is there any benefits to using a lambda over this method when there are numerous functions to be called. I'll accept this in a few minutes when timer runs out

Comment: Using a lambda function would do the same except it would have no name and in my opinion, less readable.

Comment: Your terminology is not quite right. You're not putting the function _name_ in the dictionary, you're putting a reference to the actual function.